# Access req property outside of route endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = module.exports = express.Router();
var server = require("http").Server(express);  
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
server.listen(5000);

//how to get my user.id here?


router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  io.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('order_'+req.user.id, function(data) {
        io.emit('order_'+req.user.id,data); 
    });      
  });

});
```

Above code worked well, but it has a problem. The connection get multiplied if the user refresh the page / or reenter the page. I should have put outside of the `router.get('/'..` but I have to use `req.user.id`.

Any idea how can I get user.id ??

Comment: I think on refresh client closes old connection, because client is being disconnected from server and new one should be opened on page load, so there are **no multiple connections**.

Comment: @gevorg is there such thing to disconnect on client side?

Comment: Yes there is, you cannot call it programatically, but client is being disconnected from server on page refresh. Look my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned you don't need to handle this, because on refresh client closes old connection and new page load should connect once more, so there are **no multiple connections**.

### My Sample

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('CONNECTED!');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('DISCONNECTED!');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Just refresh few times tab and you will get following output on server:

```
CONNECTED!
DISCONNECTED!
CONNECTED!
DISCONNECTED!
CONNECTED!
...
```

### Passing user id

Anyway this should be done by passing user id information from client to server and you can do it by defining new event for it, like `authenticated`

```
socket.on('authenticated', function(userId) {
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(userId + ' DISCONNECTED!');
    });
});
```

Or pass it with every event as additional data.

```
socket.on('someEvent', function(someData, userId) {
    //...
});
```

alternative could be using module like [session.socket.io](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io)

```
sessionSockets.on('connection', function (err, socket, session) {
    //your regular socket.io code goes here
    //and you can still use your io object
});
```

### Emit events from routes

In order to emit events from routes you need have some kind of connection between `express` and `socket.io`, that could be done by having mapping like this:

```
var sockets = {};
socket.on('authenticated', function(userId) {
    sockets[userId] = socket; 
    ...
});
```

and inside routes just use `sockets[userId].emit` to emit events.

### Reference

- http://socket.io/docs/#sending-volatile-messages
- http://socket.io/get-started/chat/
- https://github.com/facundoolano/socketio-auth
- https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io

Comment: I figured out where is the problem. It's because I put inside the route endpoint of express. So It will have many many init() of socket if I refresh the page.

Comment: I tried to put outside, which make the init() always once no matter how many times the user refresh or reenter the page. It worked but I have a problem, I need the `req.user.id` for my socket emit.

Comment: @JamieJordan anyway you should pass userId from client to server on some point, I suggest to do it by defining separate event like `authenticated`, look updated answer.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I think this should be marked as accepted. I have implemented my approach using socket.io events to pass the user id to the opened sockets to have an example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both logic (Express and socket.io separatelly). To get the id of the user I propose you this approach :

```
// file - app.js
// In your middleware authorization or another middleware 
// you have to pass the user to the response.
app.use(function(req, res, next){ res.locals['user'] = req.user; });
...
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
require('./sockets_controller.js')(io);
```

Now let's implement sockets_controller.js

```
global.clients = {}; // Make a global object - so you can use it everywhere
module.exports = function(io){
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('get_id_user', function(data){
        if (data){
            if (!data.id_user) return;
            this.id_user = data.id_user;
            // One client can have more than one socket opened!!
            if (clients[this.id_user]){
                clients[this.id_user][this.id] = this;
            }
            else {
                clients[this.id_user] = {};
                clients[this.id_user][this.id] = this;
            }
        }
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        if (clients[this.id_user]){
            delete clients[this.id_user][this.id];
            if(Object.keys(clients[this.id_user]).length == 0){
                delete clients[this.id_user];
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Now for your client-side (Let me supose it's JADE your rendering engine) :

```
script.
  const id_user = '#{user.id}',
  io = io.connect("...");
  io.on('connect', function(socket){
    if(id_user != 'undefined')
        io.emit('get_id_user', {
            id_user: id_user
        });
  });
```

With this, you are able to get the sockets for particular user from elsewhere.
For example in another route.

```
app.post('/whatever', function(req, res){
  for(var socketID in clients[req.user.id_user]){
    clients[req.user.id_user][socketID].emit(...);
  }
});
```

Comment: so u get user.id from Jade. How to get that in server_side? without using `route.use('/'..`

Comment: With this approach is not possible, because you need to get the id of the user in client side. The flow is : Client side receives id of the user, socket io connects to the server and send an event to identify the opened socket with the user and list is populated with the socket.

Comment: I got it worked. I use a module call node localstorage, I store the id then retrieve it. worked :D